# How to let IDEA support the Vue.js tag attributes

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, vue.js

I am use `IDEA 2016.2.5`.And I want to use `Vue.js` in project.But `vue` has some `tag attributes` that the `IDEA` did not know.The `IDEA` always highlight the error.

I had been install the `vue Plugin`. And also set the HTML `custom unknown tag attribute` , but did not work. the `v-on` always error.

http://7xrsib.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/2016-11-05%2018-04-19%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE.png

How to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `severity` in `XML>Unbound XML namespace profix` to `No highlighting, only fix`.

[image]